Why was the question "How do I hide the audit log on a Discord server?" migrated to Super User?
I'm a bit puzzled as to why the question "How do I hide the audit log on a Discord server?" was migrated to Super User, essentially marking it as off-topic. Since Discord is a web application that can be accessed using a web browser at https://discord.com/app without needing the desktop or mobile app, I would have thought it would be on-topic for Web Apps SE.
From what I can tell, the user interface for the Discord web app and the desktop app are quite similar, and the question seems to apply equally to both the web app and the desktop app versions of Discord. Can the moderators clarify the reasoning behind migrating this question to Super User instead of keeping it here on Web Apps SE?

(I'm posting this as an answer instead of a comment to the moderator's answer to have enough space to elaborate on my perspective.)
I respectfully disagree with the decision to close this question as off-topic and migrate it to Super User. I think this decision may have been based on an assumption that wasn't supported by evidence. As I mentioned earlier in the meta post about Facebook users switching to mobile apps, we should give the benefit of the doubt to the OP and assume they are asking about the web app, unless they explicitly state otherwise or mention something exclusive to the mobile or desktop app.

the question doesn't include any hint about what platform is used.

If a question clearly refers to something applicable only to the desktop or mobile app and irrelevant to the web app, then closing it as off-topic and migrating makes sense. However, in this case, the screenshot OP provided seems to be from the web app (which looks very similar or identical to the desktop app).

Discord is primarily intended for use with an installable client.

I don't think the developer's intention should determine whether a web app is on-topic here. Many other web apps, like Facebook and Instagram, are primarily meant for use with a mobile app, yet questions about their web apps, accessible from a web browser, are still considered on-topic. Unless Discord discontinues allowing access from a web browser, questions about its web app should remain on-topic for Web Apps SE.
Let's give the asker the benefit of the doubt and assume they're asking about the web app, unless they clarify otherwise. If that's the case, I believe this question is considered on-topic for Web Apps SE and should not have been migrated.

Discord is primarily intended for use with an installable client. Just look at the Getting Started help article; the web app is mentioned as an alternative for those who don't want to install an app, not as the primary option.
On the other hand, Super User has more questions than Web Applications SE. There is a higher chance that the OP question will get more visibility among users, who can guide the OP in improving the question and providing an answer.
Also, so that you know, the question doesn't include any hint about what platform is used. Considering the many Discord installable apps, there is more chance that the OP will use an installable app than the web app. There is a long history of people posting questions here, thinking this site is about any app.

So, based on your intuition that this question could be for a desktop app, you single handedly decided to migrate the question? If it was about the web app, would the question be on-topic for this site? If so, you should have asked for precisions before deciding what to do with the question. Also, if more people use the desktop app for Excel rather than the web app, would the same logic be applied? If the answer to OP's question is applicable to the web app, I fail to see why it wouldn't be a good fit for this site.

I wrote a reply to your answer here: https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5263/7584. (Given the length, I thought it would be better to post a new answer instead of a comment.)
